# Get birthday & location from user error with facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have tried the search here and also:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/signed-request/

My code worked just fine and I needed to get the birthday and location of the users of my app. So I added in the scope:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id='.$appId.'&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/'.$pagename.'?sk=app_'.$appId.'&scope=email,publish_stream,user_location,user_birthday
```

and tried to get the two extra fields like the following:

```
$first_name = $me['first_name']; 
$last_name = $me['last_name']; 
$email = $me['email']; 
$age = $me['birthday']; 
$location = $me['location'];
```

the 3 first are working but not the birtday and I get "array" when printing the location

Comment: Perhaps that specific user has not set their location. I don't get any results from `/me?fields=location`. Trying doing a `print_r()` on `$me['location']`. If it is indeed an array, take a look at the contents. There may possibly be numerous past locations there too...

Comment: I try the app with my account and have set birthday and location and also made them public.

Comment: I noticed that location is an object containing name and id, so that is why array is posted.

Comment: birthday is a date string in MM/DD/YYYY format, I have it as varchar, maybe that is the problem. Will try those..

Comment: OK the answe is:  $locationarray = $me['location']; 
 $location = $locationarray['name'];

Comment: and $age = $me['birthday']; is correct for birthdays in case someone else needs this.. thanks Lix